# Using LDAP not only for authentication but for storing data

Tags: ldap, openldap

We have multiple apps that use OpenLDAP for authentication and for storing data. We have quite lot links to these OpenLDAP entities from DBs from multiple applications (each app has its own DB), so when you change OpenLDAP entity you have to track object changes (currently we are using DN as a reference key). And inside LDAP we have few references, like what user can access which objects, as they can have very specific access rights (access right are not depend on hierarchy), LDAP also doesn't track these changes, so once these referenced objects are moved we need to track them both in LDAP and in multiple DBs.

I'm new to linux and OpenLDAP (we have it running on linux), but to me this all seems like a wrong way to handle things and it seems like we are using LDAP in the way it wasn't designed to be used (The idea of using it like this came from senior developers).

My questions is:

1. Is there anything bad to use LDAP in way i have described.
2. How can i change the OpenLDAP schema to create something like GUID for all object classes we are using, this way at least we can store object GUID instead of DN and don't have to track changes. If I change schema will I be able to perform search and filter by this GUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but your architecture description is not clear for me, so I can't write if it's bad to use it like this.

Having multiple directories in a company is very common in middle to big companies (most of the time it's due to historical reasons) but for single sign on "Meta directories" are setup to have a single authentification point.

In my point of view the DN is obsolutly not the way to point an object in a directory, jus because moving an object is changing his DN. Each directory has got an attribute inherited from the "top" class that contains an unique identifier inside the directory. In OpenLDAP it's `entryUUID`.

```
entryUUID: bec561c4-c5b0-102a-81c0-81bc30f92d57
```

If you want to link datas in a not too big Directory you can also use referential integrity, that the way users are linked to groups (when you move a user you don't have to look at each group it belongs to) in operating systems directories (RefInt Overlay in OpenLDAP).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't add entryUUID attribute, say to posixAccount entry (It also has object classes top, orgPerson, person). But i can change the schema to allow this attribute, however in this case Apache Directory studio edit this attribute as a file content. Is referential integrity can be done only by using triggers in LDAP?

Comment: For me [entrUUID](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4530) is an operational attribute (add + to your Ldapsearch command to see it). And yes as far as I know referential integrity always use some kind of triggers and introduce some requirement on the back end database.